# "Die Tickets waren innerhalb eine Woche ausverkauft" passive or active

Tags: passive

When reading the sentence

> Die Tickets waren innerhalb einer Woche ausverkauft

i.e. **The tickets were sold out in a week**

I realised *waren* is the third person plural preterite (past) conjugation of "sein" so I thought the sentence structure was active i.e. the tickets were doing the action.

I then thought, surely the tickets would receive the action of being sold out since they didn't sell themselves (someone else acted upon them - purchased them) and hence I thought:

*Why isn't the sentence above written in a passive tense?*

i.e. why don't we use the verb werden with the "ausverkaufen"?

so for example

> Die Tickets werden innerhalb einer Woche ausverkauft

Comment: Your example translates to 'the tickets will be sold out within a week'. Both your sentences are passive, as you only change the tense, so it seems to me as if the premise of your question is wrong. What do you really mean to ask?

Comment: But I thought passive needs the conjugate of the verb "werden" which isn't in the sentence I first showed - so is the sentence with "waren" passive or not?

Comment: As I already wrote: Both your sentences are passive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

German has two passive voices.

> Die Tickets werden innerhalb einer Woche ausverkauft. *(Vorgangspassiv, Präsens)*
>
> Die Tickets wurden innerhalb einer Woche ausverkauft. *(Vorgangspassiv, Präteritum)*
>
> Die Tickets sind innerhalb einer Woche ausverkauft. *(Zustandspassiv, Präsens)*
>
> Die Tickets waren innerhalb einer Woche ausverkauft. *(Zustandspassiv, Präteritum)*

You already know the *Vorgangspassiv*. That's the passive voice you know from English. It uses *werden* as its auxiliary.

The other passive voice is *Zustandspassiv* and uses *sein* as its auxiliary.

The meaning of this *Zustandspassiv* is similar to the English perfect tense, just that it's passive. Some action has been completed and what is described is the result.

It's a strange mix of the perfect aspect of tense and passive voice. (You should already know the German *Perfekt* is just the simple past in speech.) What adds another complication is some German verbs build their *Perfekt* with *sein*. For most of these, only *Perfekt aktiv* makes sense.

> Er ist gegangen.

*Gehen* is by no means a result of something.

However, for a very small group of these verbs, *Perfekt aktiv* and *Zustandspassiv* are indistinguishable.

> Sie ist gefallen.

Here, both interpretations make sense.

Comment: Precisely my point - throughout my course and in writing I have learned the need for "werden" as the passive, and now I find another form which hasn't been mentioned. How annoying! many thanks nonetheless.

Comment: You may see it as the vestiges of the perfect aspect of tenses which was lost for anything else but the passive.

Comment: That's absolutely fine but like I said it's irritating if I find such a vestiged example in the book and I spend an hour looking around for an answer that doesn't exist. Again, it was a great help, your answer.